# jQuery and mootools (jscroll-pane and rgsmoothgallery in TYPO3)

Tags: jquery, mootools, typo3

I have a pretty urgent problem regarding jquery and mootools issues.

http://www.hochzeitsfotosvonhand.de/index.php?id=24
There needs to be a scrollbar to the thumbnails of the gallery. But for now I searched and used try&error for more than five hours with no success at all.

There is a error in jQuery which I as well am not sure how to solve.

Kindly check the mentioned link with firebug for further information.

I would be really glad for any hint on this.

Best regards.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe because the javascript file for jScrollPane is blank:
http://www.hochzeitsfotosvonhand.de/fileadmin/templates/js/jquery.jscrollpane.min.js?1305544962

Comment: I believe you need to include it: http://www.kelvinluck.com/assets/jquery/jScrollPane/scripts/jScrollPane.js